# Placing external data onto Salesforce.com platform?

Tags: data, bulk-api, java

I've been trying to follow the link shown below to upload data via the bulk API tutorial from my external website onto the Salesforce.com platform:

```
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_asynch/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/asynch_api_code.htm
```

By the way if this is not the best or most efficient way to do so, please let me know and I can try that way. I'm a bit confused on the instructions here. What I've done is downloaded the Salesforce WSC toolkit .jar and partner WSDL .wsdl files. However, when I try to perform the following command as listed below:

```
java -classpath Desktop\wsc.jar com.sforce.ws.tools.wsdlc Desktop\partner.wsdl .\partner.jar
```

to compile the partner API code from the WSDL to generate partner.jar for use in my project, I keep getting an error that says

```
Could not find or load main class com.sforce.ws.tools.wsdlc
```

Any ideas on why or how to fix this? If so, that would be great! Thanks!

Comment: Java executes the Main class from a jar file, to compile use javac

Comment: I get an error saying that error: Class names, 'com.sforce.ws.tools.wsdlc,Desktop/partner.wsdl,partner.jar', are only accepted if annotation processing is explicitly requested. Any other tips?